# Using Dash along with socket API

Tags: python, sockets, plotly-dash

I want to make a webapp showing live sensor data from the mesh of our custom devices. I am familiar with Dash Python framework so I decided to use it this time as well. One of the devices communicates with W5500 shield and that is the base to start.
Unfortunatelly, when I tried to fuse Dash with BSD sockets in python, I got strange behaviour both on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) or Windows 10.

With running any Dash app with opening socket, I am getting error claiming that port/address pair is reused when still open (errno 98 on Linux or WinError 10048), although I explicitly use different interfaces and/or ports - Dash app is hosted on localhost port 8050, and I use assigned IP and other port for socket. I tried different approaches with _thread packet, but still the same error appears.

I am also aware that I do not accept a connection in this example, but as far as bind/listen doesn't work I did not put it here.

If I serve the app in seperate thread, one of them is not responsive in any way, so either I serve no app or receive no data. I am attaching example code of Dash tutorial modified in a way to show the issue.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import socket
import _thread
import atexit

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
print('socet created')
PORT = 9001
IP_ADDR = '192.168.0.38'
s.bind((IP_ADDR, PORT))

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div')
])
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
    [Input(component_id='my-id', component_property='value')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return 'You\'ve entered "{}"'.format(input_value)

def on_close():
    global s
    print('port closed')
    s.close()

def get_data(dummy):
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        print('received: ' + str(list(data)))

def run_app(dummy):
    app.run_server(debug=True)
    #while True:
    #     pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    atexit.register(on_close)

    _thread.start_new_thread( get_data, ('data',))
    #_thread.start_new_thread( run_app, ('app',) )
    app.run_server(debug=True, host = '127.0.0.1')
    while True:
        pass
```

All I really want is to keep things simple at the beginning and modify lists of values of interest, then plotting them on the live graph (whether they were updated or not) every n milliseconds.

If somebody managed to use Dash along with socket, please provide some help or hints how to establish TCP socket listening.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='my-id', value='initial value', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='my-div'),
    html.Div(id='my-hidden-div', style='hidden')
    ])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='my-div', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='my-hidden-div', component_property='children')
    [State(component_id='my-hidden-div', component_property='children')]
)
def get_data(dummy):
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024, timeout=0.1)
        print('received: ' + str(list(data)))

    return str(list(data)), str(list(data))
```

In this case the get_data callback is fired whenever the my-hidden-div is changed. 
The recvfrom times out after 100msec then spits a value back to the my-hidden-div which then calls back to the get_data callback.

I dont know if this works or not.